# Unexpected Git commit author

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have a fork of a public project in my GitHub account, and I created a new branch from my repo master in Intellij. I applied a patch with the changes I needed, committed and pushed to my branch. However, the commit author name that appeared in history was not mine, was followed by an asterisk, and the tooltip said "other name  via my name ". Any ideas what could have caused it and how to fix/prevent it in the future?

Comment: Tool-tip where? In Intellij or Github? And where is the name from? Should be from your local Git settings (maybe configured inside IntelliJ).

Comment: What kind of a patch? Git patches contain the information about the original author.

Comment: Might be a bad rebase.

Comment: The tooltip is from Intellij. I don't know where that name came from, it's not configured in Intellij...

Comment: I didn't rebase at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub has some [info about this](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/). I remember this happening to me; I think it's a known issue.